# Can nightwatchjs perform an assertion based on a reference with accuracy?

Tags: nightwatch.js

In a case where **a same** element could change for a **different** id or name depending on many factors, I would be able to do an assertion on this element with accuracy.

Doest nighwatchjs permit to do an assertion based on a relative position like can do SAHI ? (Left of this element ..., Under a div, etc.)

I want to avoid Xpath solutions, it's based on the element type (div, id, name, etc.) and if I set it to all types:

```
//*[contains(text(),'hello world')]
```

I will get many occurrences and couldn't be able to know which one I'm trying to assert.

> e.g : Running the same test on the same page, I would be able to find this "hello world" even if the div id changes or another element.

```
<div id="homebutton">
    <p>
        <a href=#>
            <span name="hm">Home</span>
        <a>
    </p>
</div>
<div id=[0-9]>
    <p>
        <a href=#>
            <span name="hw">hello world</span>
        <a>
    </p>
</div>
[...]
<div id=[0-9]>
    <p>
        <a href=#>
            <span name="hw">hello world</span>
        <a>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="logoutbutton">
    <p>
        <a href=#>
            <span name="lo">Logout</span>
        <a>
    </p>
</div>
```

> Test example : *Assert element containing string "hello world", **not the one** which is near the logout button but the one which is **near the home button**.*

Comment: Can you just have a selector based on the id?  Also keep in mind that id selectors should not start with numbers for backwards compatibility - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xpath solution is okay but here is the solution I needed, more generic and giving many more options :

Using [elements](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#elements) and manage to return an array of childrend elements

I choosed to return an array of objects with data matching my needs :

> [{ id: *webElementId*, size: {width: *18*, height: *35*}, ...}, {id: *webElementId*, ...}, etc.]

With those informations, I can do many things:

- Find an element with a specific text, attribute or cssproperty and
  perform any action on it, like assertions or click on the right of it through a calculation of his size.
- Mouse hover each elements matched (if you want to browse tabs with
  submenus ul li / ol li)

More *data* is filled, more you can perform assertions.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my previous answer, you have two options, if the Hello World you want is *always the 2nd to last, appearing just before the Logout button then you want the 2nd to last of a type, you could use an xPath selector like this:

```
"//*[.='hello world'][last()-1]"
```

That's right in the Rosetta doc I shared with you, so you *should know that by now*

Another option is to get a collection of all matches. For that, I'd write a helper function like so:

```
module.exports = {

    getCountOfElementsUseXpath : function (client, selector, value) {
        // set an empty variable to store the count of elements
        var elementCount;
        // get a collection of all elements that match the passed selector
        client.getEls(selector, function(collection) {
            // set the variable to be that collection's length      
            elementCount = collection.length;   
            // log the count of elements to the terminal
            console.log("There were " + elementCount +  " question types")      

            return elementCount;        
        });
    },

};
```

Then you can use that with some formula for how far your selector is from the last element.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, this is probably the best solution with nightwatchjs. But it's also tricky and does not support it natively, so please, edit your answer to finally answer my initial question "that It is not possible but there is alternative options ..."

Answer (score 0):

The xpath selector `"//div[contains(text(), 'hello world')]"` 
would match on both of the elements you've shown. If the element itself can change, you would use a wildcard: `"//*[contains(text(), 'hello world')]"`

For a match, on any element with that exact text:

```
"//*[.='hello world']"
```

[A great source, a "Rosetta stone",  for selector construction](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/)

To use an xpath selector with nightwatch:

```
"some test": function(client){
client
    .useXpath().waitForElementPresent("//div[contains(text(), 'hello world')]", this.timeout)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my post to give you more information about my problem. The problem is the next step, how can I assert a specific element if I find many occurrences ?

Comment: You'll see in the Rosetta stone link above some solutions for that. As well, you might want to use  the :not css selector. I'm swamped right now or I'd just write it. Also: why is xpath not an option for you? You can index into a specific one with xpath, you don't need to use the wildcard, either.